# System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. While trying to run apache2 within docker container

Tags: docker, apache, ubuntu, docker-container

I am new to Docker and i am trying my hands on with docker.

The steps I did.

1. pulled ubuntu18.04 image and ran it in an interactive way.
2. Installed apache2 with in it.

Now when I trying to run the apache i am getting the below error.
by :

```
sudo systemctl start apche2
```

Error:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

Previously I got an error with

```
systemctl command not found ubuntu
```

for which I ran a command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall systems .
```

Could anyone help me out of this?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic - please check [help/on-topic] and the [tag:apache] tag description. This is not a development/programming issue, but about running software.

Answer (score 4):

With `systemctl` you are trying to make `systemd` to run a daemon for you. This normally will not work with Docker because it is not the way Docker supposed to work. Docker usually used to create single-process containers which exist as long as the process do. That is the Docker way of running Apache2 will be running it in foreground mode: `apache2 -DFOREGROUND`.